# I need to create a method in the acount trigger to keep an external id field value updated. (continue in body)

Tags: trigger, class, custom-field, account, object

This value has to be the name of the account. Every time an account is inserted or its name changes, it is necessary to update the external id. How can i do that? thanx.

```
Public static void updateAcc ();
   List<Account> accounts = [Select Id from Account where External_Id__c = ‘’];
   for (Account account : accounts) {
     account.External_Id__c = account.Id;
   }
   update accounts;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) module on Trailhead is a good place to start if you need guidance on a trigger.

Comment: Note also that names generally make lousy external Ids because they are not unique.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add information. Do not post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public static void updateAcc ();
   List<Account> accounts = [Select Id from Account where External_Id__c = ‘’];
```

If you are in a trigger handler, presumably in a `before insert` or `before update` context, you should be working with the `Trigger.new` context variable. There is no need to perform a SOQL query.

Note that empty strings are not stored in the database. If you run a query of this kind, you must query for `null`, not `''`.

```
   for (Account account : accounts) {
     account.External_Id__c = account.Id;
   }
   update accounts;
```

This doesn't make sense. Your question stated that you need to assign the Account's *Name*, not its Id, as the External Id field. Setting another field on the same object to the Id is generally a waste of time; you should simply use the `Id` field.

If you are in an `before` trigger, which you should be for this operation, it's not necessary to perform `update` DML so long as you directly modify the sObjects in `Trigger.new`. The system automatically persists changes for you.

Your code presumably should look *something* like this:

```
for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
    a.External_Id__c = a.Name;
}
```

although I remain skeptical of the premise of using a Name field as an external Id.

Comment: thanx David, and sorry for my untidy. I'm new in code :(